# Delete empty range gap between two data sets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm beginner with vba

I have data in range A1:B20, there is in between

- A1:B4 (first set of data)
- A15:B20 (second set of data)

Length of both data sets will vary, so my goal is to:

- 1.find last used row of the first set of data
- 2a. delete empty cells which are between two sets or
- 2b. copy second data set (because the first line A15 will always be the
  same) and insert below last used row in first set of data.

I was trying with End(xlUp), I know it's a complete mess - I was trying to paste data in column C just to get started.. which turned out to not be successful yet.

```
Sub test_01()

Dim bookingWS As Worksheet
Dim copyRng As Range
Dim copyRnh As Range


Set bookingWS = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set copyRng = bookingWS.Range("A20", bookingWS.Range("A15").End(xlUp).Offset(0))


bookingWS.Range("C1:D" & copyRng.Rows.Count + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
copyRng.Copy bookingWS.Range("C1")
End Sub
```

Also I found second solution with AutoFilter, however macro deletes the first row.

```
Sub test()
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With Range("A1", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 1, ""
        On Error Resume Next
        .Offset(0).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub
```

Any advice on this will be much appreciated!

Comment: If you'd have a 1 instead of a 0 at `.Offset(0).EntireRow.Delete` you wouldn't delete the first row.

Comment: oh indeed, it works! Thanks a lot for spotting this!